# node.js+serialport receiving undefined error when writing to serialport

Tags: node.js, serial-port

Guys I'm getting error when I try to write information into serial port. I din't get any compilation errors as you can see in the result below. But When I write using **serial.write();** I get error as undefined.

```
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
This is done.
err undefined
results 2
COM3
USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA60\0001
Silicon Laboratories
```

Here is my program:

```
var comport = 'COM3';

var serialPort = require("serialport");
 serialPort.list(function (err, ports) {
  ports.forEach(function(port) {
    console.log(port.comName);
    console.log(port.pnpId);
    console.log(port.manufacturer);
  });
});

var SerialPort = serialPort.SerialPort; // localize object constructor
var newport = new SerialPort(comport, {
  baudrate: 57600
});

newport.on('open',function(){
    newport.write("S\n", function(err, results) {
        console.log('err ' + err);
        console.log('results ' + results);
      }); 
    console.log("This is done.");
});


newport.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's everything all right with your code, if the `error` parameter has the value `undefined` this means that there is no error. If the `error` parameter was an instance of an [Error constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) then you should take care of it.

An usual pattern to handle errors:

```
newport.write("S\n", function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        // Do something with the error
    } else {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```